# encontrar valor maximo y minimo numérico de varias columnas

Tags: php, mysql, update

tengo una tabla con columnas desde la A hasta la H:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito determinar con una consulta cual de las columnas es mayor y cual es menor haciendo un update.

he hecho este código pero no lo tengo claro como recorrer las columnas de la **A** a la **H** y hacer el update

```
$mayor="(SELECT MAX(numero) as ???) FROM " . TABLE . "";
$menor="(SELECT MIN(numero) as ???) FROM " . TABLE . "";
update " . TABLE . " set mayor = $mayor, menor = $menor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H,
  (
    SELECT MIN(min)
    FROM (VALUES (A), (B), (C), (D), (E), (F), (G), (H) AS v (min)
  ) AS menor,
  (
    SELECT MAX(max)
    FROM (VALUES (A), (B), (C), (D), (E), (F), (G), (H) AS v (max)
  ) AS mayor FROM selected_table;
```

Comment: Por favor expl8ca tu codigo, eso siempre se agradece